# How to close sidebar when clicking link?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get my sidebar to close when I click on any of the menu options. I was able to get the sidebar to close/open whenever I click on the burger icon, but not sure if I am supposed to make my sidebar component a class and have its own state. Below are my navigation and sidebar components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ReactComponent as MenuIcon } from '../../assets/menu.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CloseIcon } from '../../assets/x-mark.svg';
import './navigation.styles.scss';

import Sidebar from '../sidebar/sidebar.component';

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isSidebarHidden: true
    };
    this.handleSidebar = this.handleSidebar.bind(this);
  }

  handleSidebar() {
    this.setState({ isSidebarHidden: !this.state.isSidebarHidden });
  }

  render() {
    const { isSidebarHidden } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className='navigation'>
        <div className='logo-container'>
          <Link className='logo' to='/'>
            NAME
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className='navigation-options'>
          <Link className='option' to='/projects'>
            PROJECTS
          </Link>
          <Link className='option' to='contact'>
            CONTACT
          </Link>
          {isSidebarHidden ? (
            <MenuIcon className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleSidebar} />
          ) : (
            <CloseIcon className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleSidebar} />
          )}
        </div>
        {isSidebarHidden ? null : <Sidebar />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './sidebar.styles.scss';

const Sidebar = () => (
  <div className='sidebar'>
    <Link className='sidebar-option' to='/projects'>
      PROJECS
    </Link>
    <Link className='sidebar-option' to='/contact'>
      CONTACT
    </Link>
  </div>
);

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: So you want to close the sidebar when its inside menu item is clicked?

Comment: Correct. Would I have to access isSidebarHidden from Navigation component somehow?

Comment: Yes, I'll write your answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method to hide the sidebar and pass it to the Sidebar component, so it executes when you click the links.

```
const Sidebar = ({hideSidebar}) => (
  <div className='sidebar'>
    <Link onClick={hideSidebar} className='sidebar-option' to='/projects'>
      PROJECS
    </Link>
    <Link onClick={hideSidebar}  className='sidebar-option' to='/contact'>
      CONTACT
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

Or you could also execute it every time you move to a different path listening to the browser history with react-router.

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

browserHistory.listen(handleRouteChange);
```

Comment: Am I able to just use handleSidebar method I already have in navigation component?

Comment: It didnt work. I dont have to do anyhing special to have access to the method in Sidear component right? Just pass it to the component as follows `const Sidebar = ({ handleSidebar }) => (`. I did pass it to onClick to the links as you mentioned as well and no luck.

Comment: You should pass it to Sidebar as a prop this way `{isSidebarHidden ? null : <Sidebar handleSidebar={this.handleSidebar}/>}` or `{isSidebarHidden ? null : <Sidebar handleSidebar={()=>this.handleSidebar}/>}` . Sorry i didn`t clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest controlling the component with props instead of using if statement inside the parent component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './sidebar.styles.scss';

const Sidebar = ({ visibility, setVisibility }) => {

    if (visibility) {
        return (
            <div className='sidebar'>
                <Link className='sidebar-option' to='/projects' onClick={() => setVisibility()}>
                PROJECS
                </Link>
                <Link className='sidebar-option' to='/contact' onClick={() => setVisibility()}>
                CONTACT
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return null
};

export default Sidebar;
```

As you see, I passed `setVisibility` prop to `onClick` callback on the sidebar links and checked if `visibility` is `true` then return the sidebar contents. So in this step, we just need to pass `this.handleSidebar` to `setVisibility` prop and the parent state `isSidebarHidden` to the `visibility` prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ReactComponent as MenuIcon } from '../../assets/menu.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CloseIcon } from '../../assets/x-mark.svg';
import './navigation.styles.scss';

import Sidebar from '../sidebar/sidebar.component';

class Navigation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isSidebarHidden: true };
        this.handleSidebar = this.handleSidebar.bind(this);
    }

    handleSidebar() {
        this.setState({ isSidebarHidden: !this.state.isSidebarHidden });
    }

    render() {
        const { isSidebarHidden } = this.state;
        return (
        <div className='navigation'>
            <div className='logo-container'>
            <Link className='logo' to='/'>
                NAME
            </Link>
            </div>
            <div className='navigation-options'>
            <Link className='option' to='/projects'>
                PROJECTS
            </Link>
            <Link className='option' to='contact'>
                CONTACT
            </Link>
            {isSidebarHidden ? (
                <MenuIcon className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleSidebar} />
            ) : (
                <CloseIcon className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleSidebar} />
            )}
            </div>
            <Sidebar visibility={isSidebarHidden} setVisibility={this.handleSidebar} />
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the people using bootstrap offcanvas as a sidebar there is a very easy way to do it using only bootstrap and with no JavaScript.

```
<li data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
```

The above code represent li as one of the item in the sidebar and on upon clicking it takes you to skill section and also closes as it is in dismiss state.